# How to create an array of strings from images in xcassets folder?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2

I'm trying to create an app that at one point needs to select, for example, 4 pictures at random from a bank of perhaps hundreds of pictures.  I have the pictures saved in the xcassets folder.

I know one solution would be to create a string array containing the names of all the names of my pictures, and selecting one at random.  Like this, for example:

```
let pictureNames = ["pic1", "pic2", "pic3"]
let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(3)
var name = pictureNames[Int(randomNumber)]
var image : UIImage! = UIImage(named: name)
```

However, this would imply that I need to manually create an array of hundreds of names, which is hard to maintain and just sloppy, really.

Is there a way of programmatically obtaining the names of the images in this folder and putting them in an array I can use in the way mentioned above?

Bear with me... it's my first post!  I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Why you are not using for loop to create array if images name only differ with number ?

Answer (score 0):

If that's really how your pictures are names you could just use `let pictureName = "pic\(Int(arc4random_uniform(3)))"`.

Comment: That's a good point, and what I'll probably do if I don't find a different option, since i don't intend on naming the pictures this way.  But I'm really curious about how to create that array.  Or... what the approach to such an objective should be.